# Awk: How do I count occurrences of a string across columns and find the maximum across rows?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a problem with my `bash` script on Linux.

My input looks like this:

```
  input
    Karydhs     y n y y y n n y n n n y n y n 

    Markopoulos y y n n n y n y n y y n n n y

    name3       y n y n n n n n y y n y n y n
```

etc...

which y=yes and n=no and that is the results of voting... and now I want with using `awk` to display the name and the total yes vote of each person (name) and the person that win (got the most y), any ideas?

I do something like this:

```
awk '{count=0 for (I=1;i<=15;i++) if (a[I]="y") count++} {print $1,count}' filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
awk '{ for (i=2;i<NF;i++) { if ($i=="y") { a[$1" "$i]++} } } END { print "Yes tally"; l=0; for (i in a) { print i,a[i]; if (l>a[i]) { l=l } else { l=a[i];name=i }   } split(name,a," "); print "Winner is ",a[1],"with ",l,"votes"  } ' f
Yes tally
name3 y 6
Markopoulos y 6
Karydhs y 7
Winner is  Karydhs with  7 votes
```

Comment: to be more clearly I need to display for example  name1 y 7  etc

Comment: Note the limitations of this solution: the output records won't be sorted, and in the event of a tie it is unspecified which record is declared the winner.

Comment: @mklement0 why does it need to be sorted?

Comment: If the intent is to determine the entry with the most votes, one _may_ also want to sort all entries by votes in descending orders (that's not a limitation, just a choice, but it's worth mentioning). However, only reporting _one_ winner when there can be _multiple_ is a problematic limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast (no sort required, no explicit "for" loop), one-pass solution that takes into account the possibility of ties:

```
awk 'NF==0{next} 
  {name=$1; $1=""; gsub(/[^y]/,"",$0); l=length($0); 
   print name, l;
   if (mx=="" || mx < l) { mx=l; tie=""; winner=name; }
   else if (mx == l) {
          tie = 1; winner = winner", "name;
        }
  }
  END {fmt = tie ? "The winners have won %d votes each:\n" :
                   "The winner has won %d votes:\n";
       printf fmt, mx;
       print winner;
  }'
```

Output:

```
Karydhs 7
Markopoulos 7
name3 6
The winners have won 7 votes each:
Karydhs, Markopoulos
```

NOTE: The program above is presented for readability, but is accepted with the line breaks shown by GNU awk.  Certain awks disallow splitting the ternary conditional.

Comment: Kudos for reporting ties (potentially even with n > 2); just to state it explicitly, because it _appears_ that the output records are _sorted_: they are not; you report them in the same order as in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative two-pass `awk`

```
$ awk '{print $1; $1=""}1' votes | 
  awk -Fy 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0; next} {print NF-1}' | 
  sort -k2nr

Karydhs 7
Markopoulos 7
name3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another approach.

```
{ name=$1; $1=""; votes[name]=length(gensub("[^y]","","g")); }
END {asorti(votes,rank); for (r in rank) print rank[r], votes[rank[r]]; }
```

It is similar to the answer from @mklement0, but it uses `asorti()`¹ to sort inside of awk.

- `name=$1` saves the name from token 1
- `$1="";` clears token 1, which has the side effect of removing it from $0
- `votes[name]` is an array indexed by the candidate's name
- `gensub("[^y]","","g")` removes everything but 'y's from what's left of $0
- and `length()` counts them
- `asorti(votes,rank)` sorts votes by index into rank; at this point the arrays look like this:

  > ```
  > votes                 rank
  > [name3] = 6           [1] = Karydhs
  > [Markopoulos] = 7     [2] = Markopoulos
  > [Karydhs] = 7         [3] = name3
  > ```
- `for (r in rank) print rank[r], votes[rank[r]];` prints the results:

  > ```
  > Karydhs 7
  > Markopoulos 7
  > name3 6
  > ```

¹ the `asorti()` function may not be available in some versions of awk

Comment: Nice, but let's put the constraint in positive terms: This is a _GNU_ Awk solution due to use of `asorti` and `gensub` - I know of no other implementations that support them.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler - and POSIX-compliant - `awk` solution, assisted by `sort`; note that no winner information (which may apply to *multiple* lines) is explicitly printed, but the sorting by votes in descending order should make the winner(s) obvious.

```
awk '{
 printf "%s", $1
 $1=""
 yesCount=gsub("y", "")
 printf " %s\n", yesCount
 }' file | 
  sort -t ' ' -k2,2nr
```

- `printf "%s", $1` prints the name field only, without a trailing newline.
- `$1=""` clears the 1st field, causing `$0`, the input line, to be rebuilt so that it contains the vote columns only.
- `yesCount=gsub("y", "")` performs a dummy substitution that takes advantage of the fact that Awk's `gsub()` function returns the *count* of replacements performed; in effect, the return value is the number of `y` values on the line.
- `printf " %s\n", yesCount` then prints the number of yes votes as the second output field and terminates the line.
- `sort -t ' ' -k2,2,nr` then sorts the resulting lines by the second (`-k2,2`) space-separated (`-t ' '`) field, numerically (`n)`, in reverse order (`r`) so that the highest yes-vote counts appear first.